# #if EXTENDED_ALL, what does it do?

Tags: swiftui

looking at a sample swiftui App (Fruta), put together by Apple, and I see code like:

```
#if EXTENDED_ALL
...
#endif
```

But I can't find any documentation talking about this directive. Anybody know where I can find some docs on this?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the question I was really asking was "what does EXTENDED_ALL mean?", thinking it was some standard condition. But it's not, it's actually custom, specific to this particular project. It's configured in the Build settings for the project.

Answer (score 3):

That is a “Conditional Compilation Block”:

> A conditional compilation block allows code to be conditionally compiled depending on the value of one or more compilation conditions.
>
> Every conditional compilation block begins with the `#if` compilation directive and ends with the `#endif` compilation directive.

Read more in [“Compiler Control Statements” in *The Swift Programming Language*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID538).